# "VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.data::SQLConnection could not be found" after adding SQLite code

Tags: air, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

I'm working on a mobile AIR app using Flash Pro CS6 and FlashDevelop 4.3.0.

After adding SQLite to my app and trying to use the FlashDevelop debugger, FlashDevelop shows this error in the Output panel:

```
"VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.data::SQLConnection could not be found.".
```

I guess the problem is that I'm mixing several software products here, but everything worked great until the addition on SQLite code. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you importing the right libraries? When i had this error i changed to Adobe Flash Builder and Flex Mobile.

Comment: The project compiles and runs fine in Release mode. Wouldn't that imply that I use the right libraries?